# Can I login to my custom application with IAM user's credentials using AWS SDK?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Can anyone help me on how to login as an IAM user using AWS SDK?
I have an application where I want to login using AWS SDK as an IAM user. Basically, I want to allow IAM users to login into the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you generate your programamtic access keys from console?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve: Do you want your nodejs app to make calls to AWS using the sdk? Then the [SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) should help you how to achieve that. Or do you have an app where different users should be able to login, but the logins are managed by AWS.  Then you should get familiar with [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/). But there are too many possible scenarios, that anyone can give a meaningful answer with the information you have given ...

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes. I have a user whose access keys are created from the console.

Comment: @derpirscher My requirement is that, I have an app where I want to allow different IAM users to be able to login into the app. I am aware that this can be achieved using AWS Cognito. But I want to know if I can achieve this login mechanism with IAM users. Thanks.